# Why Is Bottom Half of Custom UIActionSheet with UIDatePicker Disabled?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, datepicker, uidatepicker, uiactionsheet

Everything seems to be working great with my UIActionSheet that contains a UIDatePicker except that the bottom half of the DatePicker is disabled. Visually there is a shadow that makes the bottom half of the picker darker than the top half. Everything in the bottom half is disabled and I can't for the life of me figure out how to enable it.

I also noticed in my other "normal" UIActionSheets that just contain buttons, the bottom half of the cancel buttons are disabled.

This is the code for my custom UIActionSheet:

```
self.datePickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
self.datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

self.actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose a Follow-up Date"
                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                   destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];

[self.actionSheet showInView:self.view];
[self.actionSheet addSubview:self.datePickerView];
[self.actionSheet sendSubviewToBack:self.datePickerView];
[self.actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 500)];

CGRect pickerRect = self.datePickerView.bounds;
pickerRect.origin.y = -95;
self.datePickerView.bounds = pickerRect;
```

I've tried several things including sendSubviewToBack, BringSubviewToFront, etc but I have not had any luck. I appreciate your help!

Here is a screenshot. I added the red boxes for clarification.
[alt text http://gorgando.com/UIActionSheet%20Problem.png](http://gorgando.com/UIActionSheet%20Problem.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you show your action sheet with the appropriate [`showXXX`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006801-CH3-SW9) function - I had a similar problem when showing an action sheet from a `UITabBar`; so in this case used `UIActionSheet` method `-showFromTabBar:`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just now tried this [self.actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar]; instead of my previous [self.actionSheet showInView:self.tabBarController.view]; I got exactly the same result. I think the problem must have to do with the UIActionSheet itself blocking that bottom portion from allowing user interaction.

Comment: I re-read you're question. You're far better off adding your date picker etc. to a UIView and manually animating this up and down from the bottom of the screen. I never had success with UIActionSheet used in this manner. Don't think Apple would suggest it either.

Comment: I did what you suggested with a UIView. Thanks!

Comment: Good. This was the blog which pushed me in the right direction: http://ramin.firoozye.com/2009/09/29/semi-modal-transparent-dialogs-on-the-iphone/

Answer (score 6):

Try setting the frame on your UIDatePicker instead of the bounds. I think you've got some weird stuff going on when you set the origin to -95 to position it.

Comment: This worked for me... but you have to go +95 with the frame, not -95.

Comment: Good answer. The action sheet is mid-animation when you set the bounds after the showInView. It's already calculated the final center and setting the bounds doesn't update it. Setting frame (which sets both center and bounds) does.